# CMake build subdirectory libraries as static ones

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries

With the following project structure

```
CMakeLists.txt
libs\CMakeLists.txt
```

I've got a following use case:
The CMakeLists.txt describes the build process of MyLib library. The
libs\CMakeLists.txt describes the build process of libraries used by MyLib. It is used by main project with add_subdirectory().

I can control if MyLib will be a shared or static library with:

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED=TRUE|FALSE
```

All libs used by MyLib should be linked statically (MyLib should be a "standalone" library). But I do not want to make them static explicitly in libs\CMakeLists.txt

```
using add_library(... STATIC ...)
```

as they can be used in other project as shared ones.

Can I control how my add_subdirectory(project) will be build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an option:

```
option(MYLIB_BUILD_STATIC   "Build libraries as static libraries" ON)

# add/create library
if (MYLIB_BUILD_STATIC)
    add_definitions(-DMYLIB_STATIC_BUILD)
    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES})
else (MYLIB_BUILD_STATIC)
    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
endif (MYLIB_BUILD_STATIC)
```

Comment: That's correct. Also, you can solve it without introducing a new variable by  changing and restoring BUILD_SHARED_LIBS on-the-fly.